# Cannot recognise substring in parent-string JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a parent string of which I want to replace certain entities:

[FIDDLE example here](https://jsfiddle.net/3etorypm/)

```
var parent_string = "Steven Paul Steve Jobs (February 24, 1955 – October 5, 2011) was an American information technology entrepreneur and inventor who worked with Steve Wozniak.";

var entities = {
PERSON: ['Steven Paul Steve Jobs',
    'Steve Wozniak'
],
DATE: ['February 24, 1955',
    'October 5, 2011'
]
};
```

I now loop through the entities and check whether the values are substrings of the parent string. If so, I replace them with the string `"REPLACED"`.

```
var replacement = 'REPLACED';

$.each(entities, function(key, value) {
  $.each(this, function(index, val) {
    console.log(val);
    tester = parent_string.indexOf(val);
    console.log(tester);
    var re = new RegExp(val);
    parent_string = parent_string.replace(re, replacement);
});
console.log(parent_string);
});
```

Now here is my problem: This works for the entities except for `'Steven Paul Steve Jobs'`.

The expected output would be this string:

`"REPLACED (REPLACED – REPLACED) was an American information technology entrepreneur and inventor who worked with REPLACED."`

If I do this more manually like this:

```
str = "Steven Paul Steve Jobs (February 24, 1955 – October 5, 2011)";
val = "Steven Paul Steve Jobs";
str.indexOf(val);
```

... it seems to work.

Why does this not work in my loop?

Comment: Can you paste the output that you get from the log statements and what you expect?

Comment: @AlejandroC. Yes. I've added this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the whitespace between those names is some Unicode whitespace. I suggest replacing all literal spaces with `\s+` pattern in the regex:

```
var re = new RegExp(val.replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+'));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, the regex will look like `/Steven\s+Paul\s+Steve\s+Jobs/` and `\s` will match all those whitespaces.

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3etorypm/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as you expect when copied from the question to my IDE.
It does not fully work in the fiddle because the source code of `parent-string` contains escaped HTML entities `"Steven Paul&nbsp;Steve&nbsp;Jobs&nbsp;(February...` in random positions, and therefore it doesn't match straight characters `Steven Paul Steve Jobs`. Try it outside Fiddle or tweak it to ensure the source code of your strings is unescaped in all cases. (Fiddle code inspected in Chrome).